# How to get JMeter HTML report in local time?

Tags: jmeter

Friends,

I am running JMeter on remote servers in a different timezone.  The HTML reports show all times (start, end, graphs) in the timezone of those remote servers, but I'd prefer to view them in my local time.

I have tried many of the jmeter.reportgenerator properties, including jmeter.reportgenerator.start/end_date, but nothing has produced the results I want.  Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what results do you "want".

JMeter saves the request start time in milliseconds since the beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) therefore the [.jtl file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles) is timezone-agnostic

So if you run the test on remote machine and then [generate the dashboard on the local machine](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only) - test start time will be your local.

If this is not something you "want" as well and you "want" more flexibility you might "want" to put the timezone you "want" into [*system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
user.timezone=US/Alaska
```